# Array/pointer mismatch between declaration and definition - what happens then?

Tags: c

I am going through C and came to following example which I could not understand from a book "Pointers on C". Here is the code.

The following declarations are present in one source file:

```
int     a[10];
int     *b = a;
```

But in a different source file, this code is written:

```
extern         int    *a;
extern         int    b[];
int            x, y;
...
x = a[3];
y = b[3];
```

Can someone explain what happens when the two assignment statements are executed? (Assume 
that integers and pointers both occupy four bytes.)

When I tried running the code, it gave me segmentation fault for `x` and when I comment it out and print the value of y, it gave me 0. The concept was some difference between the pointers and arrays.

Comment: Please don't write 'o/p' instead of 'output'.

Comment: So that means output! I was wondering what it meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is undefined behavior, which in your case manifests itself as a segmentation fault.

You most likely want this instead:

```
int     a[10];
int     *b = a;

extern         int    *b;
extern         int    a[];
```

And then both of your assignments will fetch `a`'s element at index 3 and put it into `x` and `y`.

Comment: no ....i want to know what happens when we use pointer instead of an array and an array instead of a pointer in different source file

Comment: I told you, undefined behavior. That's what the language standard guarantees you.

Comment: I could not understand why it is undefined behavior because we pass array to function by passing a pointer to its first variable.....it works fine there

Comment: The memory occupied by the object `a` contains 10 `ints`. `extern int *a;` tells the compiler to treat the memory occupied by the object `a` as containing a pointer to an `int` (or a pointer to an array of `ints`). Now, in the first case `a[3]` should just get you 3rd element of the array `a`. In the second case `a[3]` will *try*(!) to: extract a pointer from the object `a`'s memory, advance it by `3*sizeof(int)` bytes (via addition) and then read from that memory. If the first elements of the array `a` cannot represent a valid pointer after said addition, you get UB. Likewise w/ b.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with function parameters. It may be confusing how arrays are (mis-)treated when being passed or declared as function parameters, but that's what it is, arrays are never passed in their entirety as function parameters. Instead the pointer to the first array element is passed.